# Should 'Start' and 'End' in this arbitrary language be token regarding with the CFG?

Tags: context-free-grammar, sablecc

So, I am writing a CFG body to generate compiler via SableCC, and the given samples have these "**Start**" and "**End**" at the beginning of the program and end of it, respectively.

Sample code

```
Start
 Print 10;
 int a,b;
End
```

I suppose they are also tokens, because are not going to appear on Productions. So i wrote them in the grammar like:

```
Tokens
    number = ['0'...'9']+;
    identifier = letter(letter|number)*;
    opaddsub = '+' | '-';
    opmuldiv = '*' | '/';   
    opsemicolon = ';';
    opequal = '=';
    parleft = '(';
    parright = ')';
    comma = ',';
    blank = (' ' | 13 | 10 | 9 )+;

    start = 'Start'
    end = 'End'
```

Though I am not confident, and how i must write productions is still puzzling me, I want to get helped.